# Why wont sed remove line from file?

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to remove a specific line from a file and then append the edited line to the file. I get last part right but my sed command to remove the old line is not working.

```
sed '/^$userinput/d' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

this ends up adding all of the file contents into the new file. Instead of just the lines that I want to keep. User input is the line that I want to remove that is given by the user. This is for a BASH project I'm working on for class. I want to remove that line from the file completely by deleteing it.

```
sed "/^${1}$/d" file > otherfile
```

This adds all lines wanted and unwanted

```
sed "/^$1/d" file > otherfile
```

Creates empty file

Heres the statement that I'm workin with. Finally get it paste in.

```
update(){
read -p "Enter the course number of the course you would like to update: " updateInput  
grep $updateInput my_course.txt>update.txt  
  typeset -i status  
  typeset grade  
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]  
    then  
        read -p "Status: " status  
        while(true)  
          do  
                if [ $status -eq 0 ]  
                then  
                  break  
                elif [ $status -eq 1 ]  
                then  
                  break  
                else  
                  printf "Enter either a 0 or 1\n"  
                fi  
          done  
        read -p "Grade: " grade  
        while(true)  
          do  
                if [ $status -eq 0 ]  
                then  
                  break  
                elif [ $status -eq 1 ]  
                then  
                  break  
                else  
                  printf "Enter either a 0 or 1\n"  
                fi  
          done  
        read -p "Grade: " grade  
        while(true)  
          do  
            case $grade in  
                    A)  
                    break  
                    ;;  
                  B)  
                  break  
                    ;;  
                  C)  
                    break  
                    ;;  
              *)  
                    read -p "Enter either an A, B, C: " grade  
                ;;  
                esac  
          done  
          sed "/^$updateinput/d" my_course.txt>my_course1.txt  
          awk -F, '  
            /^CSC/{printf$1","$2","$3"," > "update1.txt"}' update.txt  
          printf $status","$grade >> update1.txt  
          cat my_course1.txt > my_course.txt  
          cat update1.txt >> my_course.txt  
          rm update.txt  
          rm update1.txt  
    fi  
    }
```

My apologizes for not posting it sooner. Ever time I tried pasting it in it told me there were errors.

After placing two lines of text in the file and calling the above script for which status was 1 and grade was A this was te output

> CSC3320,SYSTEM-LEVEL PROGRAMMING,3,1,A

This is essentially the script that alters the files. With the addition of a grep at the beginning of the function.

```
      grep $updateInput my_course.txt>update.txt  (This is at the beginning of the function. Everything else was at the bottom. )


      sed "/^$updateinput/d" my_course.txt>my_course1.txt  
      awk -F, '  
        /^CSC/{printf$1","$2","$3"," > "update1.txt"}' update.txt  
      printf $status","$grade >> update1.txt  
      cat my_course1.txt > my_course.txt  
      cat update1.txt >> my_course.txt  
      rm update.txt  
      rm update1.txt
```

Comment: Please post a minimal example of the script that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need do this because `$` means end of line regular expressions.

Try:

```
sed "/^${userinput}/d" file1.txt >> file2.txt
```

Also `>>` will append to the file.

Comment: I don't want to replace with a variable I want to remove the line completely. $userinput is the line the user wants to remove.

Comment: Oh, well if you read the line from the user then that is the same case as a variable that gets stored in a variable correct?

Comment: Yes the line read in from the user is the what is placed into $userinput and then used to search the file for the line to delete

Comment: @user2127364 Can you update the question with what is not working?  This works for me in a little script I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

`$` is a special character in sed meaning "end of line". If you want to match the literal `$userinput` at the begging of a line use `see '/^\$userinput/d'`

If you want your shell to substitute the variable `$userinput` with its content, use double quotes instead of single quotes:

```
sed "/^$userinput/d" file1.txt > file2.txt
```

or better yet

```
sed "/^${userinput}/d" file1.txt > file2.txt
```

That will remove lines starting with the value of `${userinput}`, if you want to only delete lines that are exactly the value of `${userinput}`, use

```
sed "/^${userinput}$/d" file1.txt > file2.txt
```

works for me:

```
╰─ ☭ cat file 
bar
foobar
foo
asdf
qwer
foo
asdf
╰─ ☭ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash
sed "/^${1}$/d" file > otherfile
╰─ ☭ ./script.sh foo
╰─ ☭ cat otherfile 
bar
foobar
asdf
qwer
asdf
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. For some strange reason it will work on the command line but not in the bash script file.

Comment: That didn't work either. Instead of deleting one line, or as it was doing before adding all lines, wanted and unwanted, it printed out nothing to the file.

Answer (score 0):

i did try that and found that the variable value wasnt properly replaced by the shell in the sed statement .
so the sed command instead of searching for the value as the pattern was doing a search with the variable name as pattern

ie it was trying to search $userinput as pattern @ EOL

this was due to the presence of single quotes ,  try your command again but replace them with double quotes : it worked im my sys.

code ::

```
Nitin@Kaizen ~>  cat new

#!/bin/bash

echo "the input file :"
cat INPUT2.txt ;

echo "enter line to remove" ;
read rem ;

date >> sed.log ;

sed "/$rem/d" INPUT2.txt >> sed.log;

echo "the output file :" ;
cat sed.log;
```

run ::

```
Nitin@Kaizen ~ >  ./new

the input file :
aa1
chap1
mk.t
temp.txt
z1
z2

enter line to remove
temp.txt

the output file :
Thu Mar 28 08:18:07 IST 2013
aa1
chap1
mk.t
z1
z2
```

Comment: just adds empty text to the file

Comment: its possible that the sed didnt work , it happened once - could you add set -xv in your script and check if the variable value gets replaced before the shell executes the sed statement
you should see something like this :: the sed command 
`sed "/$rem/d" INPUT2.txt >> sed.log;`  will be expanded to this :: 
`++ sed /temp.txt/d INPUT2.txt` just before execution

Answer (score 0):

figured out how to fix it.

```
update(){
read -p "Enter the course number of the course you would like to update: " updateInput
grep -v ^$updateInput my_course.txt>updatedfile.txt
grep ^$updateInput my_course.txt>editedline.txt
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
    while(true)
      do
            read -p "Status: " status
            if [ $status -eq 0 ]
            then
              break
            elif [ $status -eq 1 ]
            then
              break
            else
              printf "Enter either a 0 or 1\n"  
            fi  
      done  
    read -p "Grade: " grade  
    while(true)  
      do  
        case $grade in  
              A)  
                break  
              B)
              break
                ;;
              C)
                break
                ;;
              *)
                read -p "Enter either an A, B, C: " grade
            ;;
            esac
      done
      awk -F, '
        /^CSC/{printf$1","$2","$3"," >> "updatedfile.txt"}' editedline.txt
      printf $status","$grade"\n" >> updatedfile.txt
      cat updatedfile.txt > my_course.txt
      rm updatedfile.txt
      rm editedline.txt
  else
    printf "This course doesn't exist in your courses list.\n"
fi
}
```

In the beginning of the code I use

```
grep -v regexexperssion file1>file2
```

to get all lines in the file without the one to be removed. Then I use grep to get the actual line to be edited from the file.

```
grep regexexperssion file1>file3
```

At the bottom in the awk I perform the edits using the user generated variables on the line in file3 and then I append that to file1, which was generated with the

```
grep -v regexexpression file1>file2
```

command

NOTE the above explanation does not match the actual code used above, BECAUSE i thought it would better for people viewing this letter for a more general explanation. Also I know that there is probably a much better way to solve this problem and that the code above could probably be shortened. Any input on how to improve this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks to all those who helped me.